# Analysis of "go there", "turn left", "move back", etc

Tags: syntax, english, grammar

How are phrases such as *go there*, *turn left*, *move back* etc. analysed syntactically?

are they copula + predicate, verb + object, or something else?

Neither of these solutions seem correct to me, so I feel a bit stupid not being able to analyse such simple phrases.

Comment: I think "there", "left", and "back" in your examples are locative adjuncts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those constructions would be analysed as **verb + prepositional phrase** with *there/left/back* being analysed as full PP arguments of their verbs.

Comment: It's a bit strange to think of them as PPs, but yeah, that's definitely a better solution than the ones I mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: There's no real difference between NPs and PPs; PPs are just NPs that happen to be headed by a preposition. They're used in much the same ways in English, and PPs don't even occur much in languages with sufficiently complex case systems.

Comment: @JohnLawler, "no real difference between NPs and PPs". Could you elaborate on that? Then how come NPs can be the subject of a clause, and PPs can't? (although there might be exceptions I haven't thought of)

Comment: @dainichi Quoting Red Hot Chili Peppers: "Under the bridge downtown is where I drew some blood" has a PP as subject.

Comment: @dainichi: a preposition is a marker for a noun phrase, specifying something that could be an inflection (_to_ for dative, _with_ for comitative, etc.) It happens that English has lost all its cases and uses prepositions instead. The same thing happened to spoken Latin around 0 AD, leading to the heavy use of prepositions in Romance languages. As for subject and object, they're rarely in any other than a zero-marked case, but there are exceptions, like German dative-object passives (_Mir wurde geholfen_) and English transitivizing prepositions (_He is listened to_).

Comment: @MarkBeadles, thanks for the example. However, adding into the context clauses like "yesterday was tragic" and "write is what I do", this seems more like a proof that in English, you can zero-nominalize almost anything, than a proof that there is no difference between PPs and NPs. I'm wondering if your example construction is allowed in languages that have a subessive case, and if so, if "the bridge downtown" would be subessive, nominative, somehow both or something else.

Comment: Examples with "is" are probably not sufficient here, copulas aren't always verbs...